# replace the objects in one list with respective objects in another list

Tags: r, list, replace

`a` is a list. `a<-list(1,3,4,2,5,6)`

`b` is also a list. `b<-list(c(1,2),4,5,6,7,8)`

`p` is an indicator. `p<-c(T,F,T,T,T,T)`

If `p` is true, then we replace `a` with `b` at the respective position. Otherwise, just keep `a` as it was.

So the expected result is as follows:

```
[[1]]
[1] 1 2

[[2]]
[1] 3

[[3]]
[1] 5

[[4]]
[1] 6

[[5]]
[1] 7

[[6]]
[1] 8
```

I used the following code to calculate:

```
replace(a,b,p)
```

However, it turned out that:

```
Error in replace(a, b, p) : invalid subscript type 'list'
```

Could you help with this, thank you!

Comment: `a[p] <- b[p]`. `ifelse(p,b,a)`.

Comment: `a[p] <- b[p]` should do it?

Comment: `replace(a, p, b[p])` if you want to go that route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
a[p]<-b[p]
```

or:

```
ifelse(p, b, a)
```

Comment: Can be so easy! Thank you!